# How to get out from an iframe?

Tags: java, javascript, iframe, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an iframe like this:

```
<div id="frameDiv" style="clear: both; border: 1px solid gray;">
<iframe id="reportFrame" width="100%" frameborder="0" style="height: 800px; fit: fill; fit-position: fill; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="/InvalidData.html"/>
</div>
```

I am using to go in to the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("reportFrame");
```

Now I am able to do operations in that frame.
 I am unable to do any operations outside the frame,
I need to come out of the frame. The following is not working:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

out side that frame elements are not identifying. Help me to get out of the frame.
So that I am able to identify the elements.

Comment: Might be there is atleast one more iframe in your page other than `reportFrame` and element you're trying to interact with is likely to be in another iframe.

Answer (score 1):

before switching to the frame get the parent window handle using

```
parentWindow = Driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Now switch to the iframe and do the operation.

Again to switch back to parent window use

```
Driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow).
```

Comment: Unable to identify element in window level, it is not moving from frame to window.

Comment: can you post the html containg the other elements outside the frame you are trying to access?

Comment: This the error i am getting:  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 60.03 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can switch back to main window using

```
driver.switchTo().window("name of the main window")
```